# Agregate destinations of the same clients

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have sheet with three columns:

```
# date, name, destination
1.10. Joe, Prague
2.10. Joe, Paris
2.10. Joe, London
2.10. Bob, London
```

And I need to aggregate it using date and name. I.e., to have:

```
1.10. Joe, Prague
2.10. Joe, "Paris, London"
2.10. Bob, London
```

I tried various combination of QUERY, SELECT and GROUP BY and TEXTJOIN, but I cannot get the result I need. Is it even possible?

Comment: Since your question mentions `QUERY`, which is Google Sheets, not Excel, I updated the title and tags.

Comment: I do not mind if the solution is in Excel, Google Sheet or Calc.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to

1. create a helper column e.g. (column D) wiht unique values:
   `=UNIQUE(A:A)`
2. create a column that joins all the values in column C that correspond to each of the unique values in D:

`=join(",",query(A1:D, "select C where A = "&D1&""))`

I let the task of wrapping this into an array formula to someone else :-) Alternatively, you can just drag the results from the first cell down the bottom.